# To find a table related to others table

Tags: sql, schema

I am getting problem in finding to get all the tables related to one table in same or different DB.

Thanks
Smruti.

Comment: What RDBMS would this be for?

Answer (score 2):

Relations between tables can really only be defined in foreign keys. Without these, any 2 tables can not be connected implicitly. Things like UDFs in check constraints do not count: too opaque.

Foreign keys exist only in the same database too. There should be no related tables in another database anyway: if you have, then it can never be transactionally consistent and can never be relied upon to have the same data.

In SQL Server 2005+ you can use [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677168%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to explain how it all works. There is no single answer or query to use.